# Get link my account Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, phtml

This is the header of my website
[image: This is my header]

How to get my account to a file phtml

Comment: please explain clearly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get File using **Template Path Hint** Below way..

You can only see some settings in `developer mode`. So first of all check that you are in developer mode, if not then run this command `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` in `root` directory.

Then go to admin panel:

For Front End:

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

Comment: Thank you for your help!